How to create a Gift Certificate via an Invoice RestLet 2.0 script in Netsuite?
I need to create a Gift Certificate using the RestLet2.0 script in NetSuite. I can do this on the invoice normally on the screen, but I need to do it using a script. I'm passing giftCertCode, but it's returning an error: " org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function create in object {"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"GIFT_CERT_CODE_REQD","message":"Gift certificate codes are missing","id":"","stack":["(N/record/record Service.js)","createSalesInvoice(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:245)","(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:283)","(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:1)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"GIFT_CERT_CODE_REQD","details":"Gift certificate codes are missing","userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["(N/record/recordService.js)","createSalesInvoice(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:245)","(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:283) ","(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:1)"],"notifyOff":false},"notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}. (adhoc$-1$debugger.user#270); ID:"
This is my script:
define(["N/record", "N/search", "N/log"], function (record, search, log) {
  function createSalesInvoice(data) {
    try {
      log.debug("data", data);
      log.debug({
        title: "Data",
        details: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
      // Verifica se foram fornecidos os dados necessários para criar a fatura
      if (!data || !data.items) {
        var invoiceExistsError = error.create({
          name: "Incomplete data",
          message:
            "Be sure to provide the customer and the items for the invoice.",
          notifyOff: true,
        });
        throw invoiceExistsError;
      }

      var salesInvoice = record.create({
        type: record.Type.INVOICE,
        isDynamic: true,
      });

      if (data.formId) {
        salesInvoice.setValue({
          fieldId: "customform",
          value: data.formId, // invoice: 147
        });
      }

      if (data.customer) {
        salesInvoice.setValue({
          fieldId: "entity",
          value: data.customer,
        });
      } else {
        salesInvoice.setValue({
          fieldId: "entity",
          value: 27636113,
        });
      }

      if (data.invoiceNumber) {
        salesInvoice.setValue({
          fieldId: "custbodycustom_invoice_number",
          value: data.invoiceNumber,
        });
      }

      if (data.paymentMethodId == 1) {
        salesInvoice.setValue({
          // Fazer lógica do memo, aceitar novo campo do tipo de pagamento.. (Fazer no payment também)
          fieldId: "memo",
          value: "CASH",
        });
      } else {
        salesInvoice.setValue({
          // Fazer lógica do memo, aceitar novo campo do tipo de pagamento.. (Fazer no payment também)
          fieldId: "memo",
          value: "EMV",
        });
      }

      // salesrep
      salesInvoice.setValue({
        fieldId: "salesrep",
        value: data.salesRep,
      });

      var timestamp = data.timestamp;
      const month = Number(timestamp.substring(5, 7)) - 1;
      const newtTimestamp = new Date(
        timestamp.substring(0, 4),
        month,
        timestamp.substring(8, 10),
        timestamp.substring(11, 13),
        timestamp.substring(14, 16),
        timestamp.substring(17, 19)
      );
      // timestamp
      salesInvoice.setValue({
        fieldId: "custbodytimestamp",
        value: newtTimestamp,
      });

      if (data.locationId) {
        salesInvoice.setValue({
          fieldId: "location",
          value: data.locationId,
        });
      }

      salesInvoice.setValue({
        fieldId: "giftcertapplied",
        value: data.giftcertapplied,
      });

      salesInvoice.setValue({
        fieldId: "discountamount",
        value: data.discountamount,
      });

      salesInvoice.setValue({
        fieldId: "timediscamount",
        value: data.timediscamount,
      });

      salesInvoice.setValue({
        fieldId: "amountpaid",
        value: data.amountpaid,
      });

      data.items.forEach(function (item) {
        salesInvoice.selectNewLine({
          sublistId: "item",
        });

        // Gift Card Info
        //if (data.isNewGiftCard) {
          salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "giftcertfrom",
            value: item.giftcertfrom,
          });

          salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "giftcertcode",
            value: item.giftCertCode,
          });

          salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "giftcertrecipientname",
            value: item.giftcertrecipientname,
          });

          salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "giftcertrecipientemail",
            value: item.giftcertrecipientemail,
          });

          salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "giftcertnumber",
            value: item.giftcertnumber,
          });

          salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "description",
            value: item.description,
          });
        //}
        // fim

        salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: "item",
          fieldId: "item",
          value: item.item,
        });

        salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: "item",
          fieldId: "quantity",
          value: item.quantity,
        });

        salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: "item",
          fieldId: "trandate",
          value: item.trandate,
        });

        // LOCATION
        salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: "item",
          fieldId: "location",
          value: item.location,
        });

        if (item.discountedAmount) {
          salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "custcol_gwsv_disc_amount",
            value: item.discountedAmount,
          });
        }

        salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: "item",
          fieldId: "account",
          value: item.account,
        });

        //PO/CHECK NUMBER
        salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: "item",
          fieldId: "otherrefnum",
          value: item.otherrefnum,
        });

        //AMOUNT
        salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: "item",
          fieldId: "total",
          value: item.total,
        });

        salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: "item",
          fieldId: "rate",
          value: item.rate,
        });
        
        salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: "item",
          fieldId: "amount",
          value: item.amount,
        });
        
        salesInvoice.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: "item",
          fieldId: "giftcertmessage",
          value: item.giftcertmessage,
        });

        salesInvoice.commitLine({
          sublistId: "item",
        });
      });

      var invoiceId = salesInvoice.save();

      var invoiceData = search.create({
        type: search.Type.INVOICE,
        filters: [["internalid", "is", invoiceId]],
        columns: ["internalid", "tranid"],
      });

      var searchInvoiceResults = invoiceData
        .run()
        .getRange({ start: 0, end: 1 });

      var transactionId = "Not exist";

      if (searchInvoiceResults && searchInvoiceResults.length > 0) {
        transactionId = searchInvoiceResults[0].getValue("tranid");
      }

      return JSON.stringify({
        success: true,
        message: "Invoice created",
        invoiceId: invoiceId,
        invoiceNumber: transactionId,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      var invoiceExistsError = error.create({
        name: "Error",
        message: error.message + " DataReceived: " + JSON.stringify(data),
        notifyOff: true,
      });
      throw invoiceExistsError;
    }
  }

  return {
    post: createSalesInvoice,
  };

  
});

In the documentation (https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2018_1/script/record/giftcertificate.html) there is the giftCertCode field, but in the invoice documentation (https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2018_1/script/record/invoice.html) there is not, therefore it gives the error. I am trying to create it through an invoice because in the NetSuite forum (which I am not allowed to send questions because my registration is recent) one of the questions about this, it was clarified that to create a new Gift Certificate it needs to be through an invoice passing the Gift Certificate Item Id.

I would suggest Instead of directly setting giftcertcode, Let NetSuite handle code generation automatically.
